# How to reduce a String to an Integer summing its characters

Tags: groovy

I'd like to take a String e.g. "1234" and convert it to an Integer which represents the sum of all the characters.

I thought perhaps treating the String as a List of characters and doing a reduce / inject, would be the simplest mechanism.  However, In all my attempts I have not managed to succeed in getting the syntax correct.

I attempted something along these lines without success.

```
    int sum = myString.inject (0, { Integer accu, Character value ->
        return accu + Character.getNumericValue(value)
    })
```

Can you help me determine a simple syntax to resolve this problem (I can easily solve it in an java like verbose way with loops etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
"1234".collect { it.toInteger() }.sum()
```

Solution by @dmahapatro

```
"1234".toList()*.toInteger().sum()
```

Comment: awesome! Exactly what I need - I didn't know about the sum method.  thanks

Comment: Or `"1234".toList()*.toInteger().sum()`. :)